# htaccess multi domain redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

How can us set .htacess for multi domains to diffrent folder.

That is so far i got.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain [L]
```

Then the URL www.domain.com redirect to www.domain.com/domain

Now i want to delete the folder so that i only get **www.domain.com**

**Next is i need this for 3 domains.**

- www.domain.com -> /domain
- www.foo.com -> /foo
- www.bar.com -> /bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^/]+)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}//%1 ^(www\.)?(.+)\.com//\2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)$ /$2 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %2//$1 !^(.+)//\1$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*)$ /%2/$1$2 [L]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: @Matthias sorry, typo, one of those COnd should be Rule, also the %1 should be %2 in the last rule

Comment: Work's perfect. How can i do the same for subdomains? so if i have folder.domain.com that he rederict to /folder

Comment: So when i use your code i get for subdomains The requested URL /folder.domain/index.php was not found on this server. and i only need /folder/

Comment: It's not going to work for subdomains, that's going to require an entirely different solution

Comment: Ok. Now i will do it for all domains and subdomain separated. :) It works. But your solution is very nice.